# Java JPannel not Visible

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtextfield

I tried creating simple GUI using JFrame with below code.

```
package sorting_array_gui;

package sorting_array_gui;



import java.awt.BorderLayout; 
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import javax.swing.JTable;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class userwindow extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



public userwindow() {
        super("A Programm to Sort Your Array");
        setSize(1000,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        JPanel p1= new JPanel();

        JButton b1= new JButton("Click Here");
        p1.add(b1);

        JTextField t1= new JTextField();


        p1.add(t1);
        JLabel l1= new JLabel("This is a Lable");
        p1.add(l1);



        add(p1,BorderLayout.CENTER);



}


}
```

When I added JTextfield ,  JPlane misbehaved and even JButton and JLabel stoped showing.
Why is that happening.

Answer (score 2):

> "When I added JTextfield , JPlane misbehaved and even JButton and JLabel stoped showing."

I don't get this behavior with your code. But you should note the below.

- `setVisible(true);` should be that *last* thing you do *after* adding all components.

  ```
  public userwindow() {
      super("A Programm to Sort Your Array");
      JPanel p1= new JPanel();
      JButton b1= new JButton("Click Here");
      p1.add(b1);
      JTextField t1= new JTextField();
      p1.add(t1);
      JLabel l1= new JLabel("This is a Lable");
      p1.add(l1);
      add(p1,BorderLayout.CENTER);


      pack();                                                  <--- PACK frame
      setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setVisible(true);                                        <--- LAST

  }
  ```
- Also, you should set a size to your text field using the constructor that sets the column size

  ```
  JTextField t1 = new JTextField(20);
  ```
- Also, you should use `pack()` instead of `setSize()`. If you just `pack()`, *everything* should be visible, as the preferred sizes of all the components are respected.
- Also note, if you want to add any other components to the `JFrame` you need to specify a `BorderLayout` position for *each* component, with *no* positions being used more than once.
  See [**Laying out Components Within a Container**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)